# What is the best way to simulate real time performance testing in Mobile browsers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobile, jmeter, appium, performance-testing

I am working on Mobile Testing of Web Application. I have done real-time performance measurement in chrome browser using JMeter and Web Driver sampler.

Now, I want to do the same in real mobile devices.

For example, if 10 users need to log in, I want to simulate it in multiple mobile devices. Kindly suggest me the best way to do the mobile performance testing.

Since I am working on a web application, it mostly involves in Chrome browser and gmail app's default browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate multiple users concurrently accessing your application backend the best way would be going for JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers as real browsers are **very** resource intensive.

1. Record your mobile device network activity using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), check out [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for instructions.
2. If your goal is to simulate different devices you can configure relevant [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header in the [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
3. Set up [as many threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) as needed in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
4. Run your test and analyze results